# jquery how to get form element types, names and values

Tags: jquery, forms, element

I know I can get the name/value relationship by using

```
$(#form).serializeArray();
```

But is there a way to get the whole enchilada, type, name and value with one call?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `$("form :input")`

Per the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/):

> Description: Selects all input,
>   textarea, select and button elements.

Now to your question,

> there a way to get the whole
>   enchilada, type, name and value with
>   one call?

If you simply want to loop through the items,

```
$("form :input").each(function(index, elm){
  //Do something amazing...
});
```

But if you want to return some sort of structure, you can use `.map()`

```
var items = $("form :input").map(function(index, elm) {
    return {name: elm.name, type:elm.type, value: $(elm).val()};
});
```

Or if you simply want to get the elements

```
$("form :input").get()
```

**[Example of this on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/kkKb8/)**

Comment: Yes this is the best approach if you want to also retrieve the submit button.

Answer (score 4):

The below code helps to get the details of elements from the specific form with the form id,

```
$('#formId input, #formId select').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = $(this);
        alert('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + 'Name: ' + input.attr('name') + 'Value: ' + input.val());
    }
):
```

The below code helps to get the details of elements from all the forms which are place in the loading page,

```
$('form input, form select').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = $(this);
        alert('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + 'Name: ' + input.attr('name') + 'Value: ' + input.val());
    }
):
```

The below code helps to get the details of elements which are place in the loading page even when the element is not place inside the  tag,

```
$('input, select').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = $(this);
        alert('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + 'Name: ' + input.attr('name') + 'Value: ' + input.val());
    }
):
```

**NOTE:** We add the more element tag name what we need in the object list like as below,

```
Example: to get name of attribute "fieldset",

$('input, select, fieldset').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = $(this);
        alert('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + 'Name: ' + input.attr('name') + 'Value: ' + input.val());
    }
):
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you loop through each `input` element of the form and use the data you get from there? Something like this:

```
$('form input').each(function(i, v) {
    // Access like this:
    //   $(this).attr('type');
    //   $(this).attr('value');
    //   $(this).attr('name');
});
```

Comment: I was just reading up on .each and .map to see if they would help. : D /n/n I know I can get all inputs that way but what about select and textareas?

Comment: Well you could modify the selector to use `form input, form select, form textarea`

Comment: It is best practice in programming to spell out each variable for what it does. With most IDE's now having auto complete there is no need to use since letter variables. Instead of `i` use `index` and instead of `v` use `value`

Comment: Duh, yeah I could, if I wanted to make it easy on myself and all that... : D  I'm in forest and trees mode here, missing obvious stuff...

Comment: Why select value as an attribute when you could just use `.val()`?

Comment: No reason. It won't work though when using `form select` and `form textarea` in the selector. But in my example above, you'll get the same result either way.

Answer (score 2):

To get ALL form elements use

```
$('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
    //   $(this).attr('type');
    //   $(this).attr('name');
    //   $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: here's what I looking for. elegant & simple to hold this for my better code optimization.. You are Great Dear @Bot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) will be more useful but you'll still have to filter elements of interest yourself, unless you use a selector.

You might also do the following if you only want to select [`successful`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) elements in the form; this will NOT include buttons or disabled fields.

```
$($('#testf').serializeArray()).each(function(index, value){
    $('#testf [name="' + value.name + '"]'); //select the named element
});
```

Mark's answer seems like the best way, IMO.

Comment: This will include any HTML that is listed inside the form tags as a child.

Comment: What jostster said, then I get all the labels, <p> tags and what not within the <form></form>

Comment: @jostster I know, that's what children() does but I should've probably clarified - I've updated my answer. Thanks