# Jquery getting nested inputs of Div, placing in Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested-loops

I am at my wits end with this nested loop.
I am trying to create an object with nested objects in it grouped by the containing div id.
So far this is what I have:

```
$('#survey-submit').on('click', function (e) {


    var formData = {};
    var item = {};
        $("div[id^='question-']").each(function () {
            var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
            var $this = $(this);
            formData[id] = $this.children('input, select,checkbox').each(function () {
                item[this.name] = this.value;
            });


            //console.debug(formData);
        });
        console.debug(formData);
    return false;
});
```

The result of the console log is all the input elements of the divs that have the start like question, I get the expected number of new objects all dynamically named, but they all contain the same thing.

The contents of each object are not specific to the this object I am trying to generate it from, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think `each` works the way you think it does http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: I'll take a look at that. Any other function you think could do what I am trying to do here?

Comment: You can do it with `each`, but it doesn't reassign `this` to the variable. Put in the `index` and `value` arguments and use `value` instead of `this`.

Comment: Okay, I will give that a try. And update here based on my results

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you are using the containing div to filter anything. You can do something like `var emptyTextBoxes = $(e.target).find('input.surveyInputs')...`

Comment: I editted the code for clarity. The emptyboxes parts were for error handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem here : [jquery how to get form element types, names and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666445/jquery-how-to-get-form-element-types-names-and-values)

I wound up doing this:

```
    $("div[id^='question-']").each(function () {
            var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
            var $this = $(this);
      var inputs= $(id+' :input').map(function(index, elm) {
    return {name: elm.name, value: $(elm).val()};
}).get();
       formData[id]=inputs;
        });
```