# set custom attributes from json serializeArray

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to set my inputs's attributes "optionprix" from a json serializeArray

Here it's my json serializeArray, var sortableContent = :

```
[{"name":"checkboxes-label---3499163","value":"Options"},{"name":"single-checkbox---3499163","value":"Option1","optionprix":"5"},{"name":"single-checkbox---3499164","value":"Option2","optionprix":"6"},{"name":"single-checkbox---3499165","value":"Option3","optionprix":"7"},{"name":"single-checkbox---3499166","value":"Option4","optionprix":"8"},{"name":"required---3499163","value":false}]
```

And my actual Jquery who catch only val from my json :

```
function update_CF_Data(CF_SortablesForm){
    var CF_SortablesForm = $('#sortables-form');
    var sortableContent = JSON.stringify(CF_SortablesForm.serializeArray());
    $('#myform_fields').val(sortableContent);
    $('#myform_fields').attr('optionprix');
}
```

html part :

```
<div id="myform_fields">
<form id="sortables-form">
<ul>
<li>
<input class="optionname" name="single-checkbox---3499163" value="Option1" optionprix="5" type="text">
<input class="optionname" name="single-checkbox---3499164" value="Option2" optionprix="6" type="text">
<input class="optionname" name="single-checkbox---3499165" value="Option3" optionprix="7" type="text">
<input class="optionname" name="single-checkbox---3499166" value="Option4" optionprix="8" type="text">
</li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>
```

How to correctly catch both value and optionprix from my json ?

Comment: Is `update_CF_Data` method calling multiple times based on JSON array? OR `myform_fields` need to capture multiple values?

Comment: not sure to understand the question for update_CF_Data, but myform_fields need to capture values and custom attributes (optionprix)
I edited my question with the html part

Comment: `sortableContent` Json will have multiple values. So, how you'll store it into single `#myform_fields` field?

Comment: with php function I will use foreach to print every values and attributes optionprix into the myform_fields

Comment: Sorry man, I'm not getting cleary and confused. When you're calling `update_CF_Data()` method? From where `CF_SortablesForm` variable value coming?

Comment: this method update_CF_Data() is called in various point like when using a validating by a bouton.
My project is a page where first I load the json data array and print it into the html div myform_fields
After that when I call the function update_CF_Data I want to update my json. Actually that's work fine but update only "value" and I want to record too "optionsprix" attribues.

Comment: Now, I got the point. `serializeArray` will return only name and value. For other attributes, Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666445/jquery-how-to-get-form-element-types-names-and-values